# Finding the center of a contour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code that produces some contours for an image. What's the best way to also calculate the centre pixel of the last contour.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
levels = []
for i in np.arange(0.1,0.9, 0.1):
    levels.append(i*40)
s = plt.contour(Y, X, twhole, levels, linewidths=1, colors=('k','#0000ff', '#0033ff', '#0066ff', '#0099ff','#00ccff','#00ffff', '#660000' ))#'k','0.5','0.75','0.8','0.9', 'g','c','b','m','y','r', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', ))#colors='k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: how do you define the 'centre pixel' if the contour is an irregular shape?

Comment: I guess minimising the average distance from the edges

Comment: OK, so what have you tried so far? Note that you can get a list of the coordinates for each contour line from `s.allsegs`.

Comment: So what you are looking for is a [centroid of a polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_a_polygon)? Even if it means in the case of a C like shape that it lies outside the polygon?

Answer (score 1):

If `s = ax.contour(...)`, you get the last contour line's points via 
`s.allsegs[-1][0]`.

You may use those to calculate the centroid of the points in the usual way, see e.g. wikipedia [Centroid of a polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_a_polygon),

> [image]

Some example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def center_of_mass(X):
    # calculate center of mass of a closed polygon
    x = X[:,0]
    y = X[:,1]
    g = (x[:-1]*y[1:] - x[1:]*y[:-1])
    A = 0.5*g.sum()
    cx = ((x[:-1] + x[1:])*g).sum()
    cy = ((y[:-1] + y[1:])*g).sum()
    return 1./(6*A)*np.array([cx,cy])


X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2),np.linspace(-1,4))
f = lambda x,y: np.exp(-x**2-y**2)+np.sin(np.arctan2(y,x))
Z = f(X,Y)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap="Reds", vmax=10)

contour = ax.contour(X,Y,Z,levels=[1.01,1.1,1.2], colors="k")

c =  center_of_mass(contour.allsegs[-1][0])
ax.plot(c[0],c[1], marker="o", markersize=12, color="red")
plt.show()
```

[image]